# Hermitian Matrix computing $w^{H}z$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\mathbb C^{n}$ denote the vector space of all n tuples of complex numbers. $\mathbb R^n $ real inner product space.

As a notational convenience we write $z^H$ for the transpose of $\overline z$

$ \\z^T=z^H,||z||=(z^Hz)^{1/2} \\ \\ \\$

### $ \mathbb R^{n} \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \  \ \ \ \ \ \qquad \ \ \mathbb C^n$

---

$<x,y>= y^Tx \qquad \ \ \  \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \  \ \  \ \ \  \ \ \  \  \ \ \  \ \ \ <z,w>=w^Hz \\x^Ty=y^Tx\qquad \ \ \  \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \  \ \  \ \ \  \ \ \  \  \ \ \  \ \ \ \  \ \ \  \ \ \  \ \ \ z^Hw=\overline{w^Hz} \\||x||^2=x^Tx \qquad \ \ \  \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \  \ \  \ \ \  \ \ \  \  \ \ \  \ \ \ \  \ \ \  \ \ \  \ \ ||z||^2=z^Hz$

If

$$
   z=     \begin{bmatrix}
        5+i \\
        1 -3i \\
        \end{bmatrix} \text{and } w=\begin{bmatrix}
        2+i \\
        -2+3i \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
$$

then to find $w^{H}z$ we use the complex conjugate

$w^{H}z =(2-i,-2-3i) \begin{bmatrix}
        5+i \\
        1 -3i \\
        \end{bmatrix} =0$

$z^{H}z= |5+i|^2+|1-3i|^2= 16+4i $

However the answer is $36$.How does one get this? And.

$w^Hw = |2+i|^2+|-2+3i|^2=?$

How does one answer the question above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result for $z^Hz$ is wrong.  Note that $|a + bi| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ (for real numbers $a,b$); you seem to be under the *incorrect* impression that $|a + bi| = |a| + |b|i$.  We have
$$
z^Hz = |5 + i|^2 + |1 - 3i|^2 = (5)^2 + (1)^2 + (1)^2 + (-3)^2 = 36
$$

Comment: Its all to the absolute value based on the norm vector space.

Comment: I don't know what that comment means

Comment: Like if x is a $\text{vector } (4,-5,3)^T$ in $R^3$ $||x||_1 = |4| +|-5| +|3|=12$. And A normed vector space is a pair $(V, ‖·‖ )$ where V is a vector space and $‖·‖ $a norm on V. That's all I meant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space

Comment: I know what a normed vector space is, I just have no idea what you were trying to say.  Doesn't really matter, glad you understand how complex numbers work now.

Comment: I was wondering why $i^2=-1$ but $ |-1| =1$. Based on your work from above made me realize this.